# Google blank search result

Tags: google-search

Why is there a completely blank Google search result?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPk9K.png)

Proof:
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NDCM_enUS834US834&q=www.agariopvp.org&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3h4mFt4XhAhVKnq0KHRCRAsEQBQgrKAA&biw=1280&bih=529

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for questions about programming only.

Answer (score 0):

The link you are searching for have no description to show that's why its showing blank result.
Google is also not able to read the title of the link so it's showing just showing the link.
And if you want to why Google is not able get title and description of that webpage then you have to contact to Google.